# Modeling Wheel Deceleration

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics, differential-equations

***Help!***

Wheel should decelerate according to $e^t$ but actually decelerates at $t^2$.

**Preface**

The other day riding my bike home I found I had a loose hub. When tightening a hub there is a risk of [overtightening](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cone-adjustment.html), which increases the friction on the wheel. The range of proper adjustment is narrow and, while I could simply watch how fast the wheel spun after I had tightened, I wanted to know precisely how much friction was slowing my wheel, depending on how tight I had tightened it. (Knowing these frictional forces could prove helpful in judging hubs in general, and not only how tight they are.)

**Experiment**

I turned my bike upside down and spun my wheel. I recorded the duration of each full rotation. I timed these rotations by eye, watching for when the valve passed the fork, and tapping my phone's stop watch app. This process obviously introduces a lot of human-based variance but my data set seems to be clear enough. I perform this process twenty times, making adjustments to the hub after every few trials.

**Expected Model**

As Huang and Nagarka [present](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/117f/b63e8cf3fcc0daff0b727bb92158c84614b0.pdf), a free bicycle wheel experiences viscous and dry friction. It should therefore behave according to the following equation of motion

$Jω' + Bω + T_c = 0$

where *B* is the viscous friction coefficient and $T_c$ is the friction torque. *J* is the moment of inertia.

If we solve this ODE we arrive at

*$ω(t) = ae^{bt} - c$*.

In order to identify the individual quantities of friction I will need to expand *a*, *b*, and *c*, but for now they nicely simplify everything.

**Plotting the Data**

I open up R and plot my results.

[image]

However, because my knowledge of R only allows for linear regression models, and to avoid subtraction with a logarithm, I take the derivative

$ω'(t) = abe^{bt}$

and plot $\ln ω'$ against time, because $\ln (e^{bt})$ is, of course *bt*. (Because all my $ω'$ values are negative I actually plot *ln -ω*. We expect a linear relationship.

[image]

Instead we find a relationship which looks logarithmic, indicating that the wheel's deceleration is not following $abe^{bt}$. In recognition of the logarithmic shape of this plot, I take the logarithm of time. I plot $\ln ω'$ against $\ln t$.

[image]

This relationship, now, appears linear, and therefore it seems that the motion can be modeled by $\ln ω' = a \times \ln t + b$ which is equivalent to

$ω = c t^a$

where $c$ is introduced to represent the coefficient $e^b$. When I run a regression model on this form I find that $c = 2.16$ and $a = -2.07$; more relevantly my R-squared value is 0.999 and my adjusted R-squared value is 0.9989. Simply seeing the $\ln ω$ against time plot is enough to show the inadequacy of the model but, in comparison, its R-squared value was a 0.7637.

Now, this plot appears to follow $ω = 2.16 t ^{-2.07}$ but when I plot the residuals I find a surprisingly biased result:

[image]

**Question**

Essentially, *I am curious why my data does not match the provided equation of motion*. I foresee two possible explanations:

1. My math is wrong.
2. The equation of motion is missing a very important force.

The first is likely; the second I struggle to understand physically. Sure there are easily forces not being taken into account, but this should not transform the motion into a power function. Also, though, the residuals demonstrate that the relationship is not actually a simple power function, even if it appears to be.

**Note:* A [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106354/calculating-the-time-to-stop-a-wheel-with-friction) on calculating a wheel's stopping time was already asked, but closed for resemblance to homework, without sufficient research.*

Comment: Does the speed really drop by half in about 3 seconds?  From ~2.8 rad/s to 1.4 rad/s?  That seems excessive in terms of friction, especially since it corresponds to around walking speed.

Comment: @DMPalmer what makes you think that points are spaced every second? I'd guess they're spaced every 2 s for low t. So the speed would drop by half after 6 seconds, not 3 seconds. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your values of $t$ for small $t$, I figured out that you've got a bug in your R code. You're incorrectly calculating $\omega(t)$ as
$$\omega(t)=\frac{2\pi}{t}\ \ .$$
You need to calculate $\omega(t)$ as
$$\omega(t)=\frac{2\pi}{\Delta t}\ \ ,$$
where $\Delta t$ is the difference between consecutive measured values of $t$.

Comment: Bah you're right, added a column in my google sheet before sending to R and it threw it all off. heh thanks